# Pattern decoding

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I need a little help in the following. I have this kind of datafile:

```
0 0    # <--- Group 1 -- 1 house (0) and 1 room (0)

0 0    # <--- Group 2 -- 2 houses (0;1) and 3,2 rooms (0,1,2;0,1)
0 1
0 2    
1 0    # <--- house 2 in Group 2, with the first room (0)
1 1    # <--- house 2 in Group 2, with the second room (1)

0 0    # <--- Group 3
0 1    # <--- house 1 in Group 3, with the second room (1)
0 2

0 0    # <--- Group 4
1 0    # <--- house 2 in Group 4, with one room only (0)
2 0
3 0    # <--- house 4 in Group 4, with one room only (0)

0 0    # <--- Group 5

0 0    # <--- Group 6
```

There are some cases, which have to be answered:

There are groups in the example; there exists a group, if it is separated by new lines from the other, so in this case we have 6 groups. We have to determine the followings

Get the actual number (ordinal number) of the group (the counter starts for example from 1)

- if the 1st column = 0 and the 2nd column = 0 and the next line is empty
  So the desired output according to the above example would be

  `1`
  `5`
  `6`
- if the first column = 0 and the 2nd column can vary and the next line is empty
  So the desired output according to the above example would be

  `3`
- ... etc. How can this be generalized in a way that we can set at the beginning which case would we like to get ? 
  There might be many cases according to the values of the columns in a group.

We can imagine this if we think about something like this: the first column means the number of houses in a street, and the second column means the number of rooms in a house. Now I would like to find all possible kind of streets in a city, which means for example

let us pick up those streets, in which there are two houses with different number of rooms, in the first house there are 3 rooms, and in the second house there are 2 rooms. So we have the get output **`2`**, becasue this requirement fulfills this group in the file

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
```

**Important: `0 0` means there is one house with one room**

**Correction**: if there is one house only, then it has just one room all the time! Like in the cases Group 1, Group 5, and Group 6. Remember, that the second column is the number of room, and 0 mean "1 room", 1 means "2 rooms", ...etc. This is just a counter which starts from 0, instead of 1, sorry if it is confusing a little bit...

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to sort the groups by their last line? In your street and house example, what does a group represent?

Comment: I've read it about three times, and didn't understand the group/street/house/room trick ...

Comment: I don't blame you @Kent .. I am seeing little birdies myself.

Comment: Ok, so a group represents a house,room doublets. There are 6 groups in the example (if there is a blank line then that is the separator between different groups...) If I take the case when there is 1 house with one room 0 0, then there are 3 matches, and these are the number group 1, 5 and 6.

Comment: If I say, that I am looking for those streets (groups), in which there are 2 houses with 3 rooms in one house and with 2 rooms in another one, then I should get `2` as result, because the only group which satisfies this condition is the second group.

Comment: Here at the Planning Dept we need an output format for all these houses!

Comment: Are the houses and rooms always numbered as 0, 1, 2...? Or can you have a group like `2 4, 2 5, 1 7, 1 2` (identical to `0 0, 0 1, 1 0, 1 1`)?

Comment: No, you can't. The groups and the rooms are starting from 0, and goes continuously like in the example, so you do not have a group like 2 4, or 1 2. Every time you print out the actual room number you have to specify the actual house number too. That's why you have a group like the 3rd one in the example above... (0 0 \n 0 1 \n 0 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what would be your expected output, however I have converted/decoded your number pattern to a meaningful group/house/rooms format. any further "query" could be done on this content.

see below:

```
kent$  cat file
0 0

0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1

0 0
0 1
0 2

0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0

0 0

0 0
```

awk:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} 
        { print "\ngroup "++g; 
        delete a;
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i%2) a[$i]++;
        for(x in a) printf "House#: %s , Room(s): %s \n", x, a[x]; }' file
```

we get output:

```
group 1
House#: 0 , Room(s): 1 

group 2
House#: 0 , Room(s): 3 
House#: 1 , Room(s): 2 

group 3
House#: 0 , Room(s): 3 

group 4
House#: 0 , Room(s): 1 
House#: 1 , Room(s): 1 
House#: 2 , Room(s): 1 
House#: 3 , Room(s): 1 

group 5
House#: 0 , Room(s): 1 

group 6
House#: 0 , Room(s): 1
```

**note** that the generated format could be changed to fit your "filter" or "query"

**UPDATE**

OP's comment:

> I need to know, the number of the group(s) which have/has for example
>   1 house with one room. The output would be in the above case: 1, 5 ,6

as I said, based on your query criteria, we could adjust the awk output for next step. now I change the awk abovet to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} 
        {print "";  gid=++g; 
        delete a;
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i%2) a[$i]++;
        for(x in a) printf "%s %s %s\n", gid,x, a[x]; }' file
```

this will output:

```
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1

6 0 1
```

the format is g`roupIdx houseIdx numberOfRooms` and there is a blank line between groups. we save the text above to a file named **decoded.txt**

so your query could be done on this text:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"}{if (NF==3 && $3==1)print $1}' decoded.txt
1
5
6
```

the last awk line above means, print the group number, if room number ($3) = 1 and there is only one line in the group block.

Comment: Nice!! Can you please tell me why we use the `delete a` type of syntax. I have seen it in some of your answers here on SO, but never really understood it's significance.

Comment: @JaypalSingh delete just for cleaning the array. you can try to remove the delete line, then execute the awk script, see the different.

Comment: Ok, thanks the conversion. So, I need to know, the number of the group(s) which have/has for example 1 house with one room. The output would be in the above case: 1, 5 ,6. See also the correction in my post!

Comment: Thank you, but the last `awk` line does not work for me, this does not print out anything... I have already checked that the decoded.txt file as the same as yours, and it is. By the way, what does NF==4 mean? Does it mean that the next line is a blank line?

Comment: @user1116360 the awk line works here. I guess it would be the empty lines in the decoded.txt. try this:  awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"}{if (NF==3 && $3==1)print $1}' decoded.txt

Answer (score 2):

I would first define a House class and a Group class:

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, rooms):
        self.rooms = rooms


class Group:
    def __init__(self, index, houses):
        self.index = index
        # houses.values() is a list with number of rooms for each house.
        self.houses = [House(houses[house_nr]) for house_nr in sorted(houses)]

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Group {}'.format(self.index)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Group {}'.format(self.index)
```

Then parse the data into this hierarchical structure:

```
with open('in.txt') as f:             
    groups = []

    # Variable to accumulate current group.
    group = collections.defaultdict(int)

    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
            # Empty line found, create a new group.
            groups.append(Group(i, group))
            # Reset accumulator.
            group = collections.defaultdict(int)
            i += 1
            continue

        house_nr, room_nr = line.split()
        group[house_nr] += 1
    # Create the last group at EOF
    groups.append(Group(i, group))
```

Then you can do stuff like this:

```
found = filter(
    lambda g:
        len(g.houses) == 1 and # Group contains one house
        g.houses[0].rooms == 1, # First house contains one room
    groups)
print(list(found)) # Prints [Group 1, Group 5, Group 6]

found = filter(
    lambda g:
        len(g.houses) == 2 and # Group contains two houses
        g.houses[0].rooms == 3 and # First house contains three rooms
        g.houses[1].rooms == 2, # Second house contains two rooms
    groups)
print(list(found)) # Prints [Group 2]
```

Comment: In what kind of language are you working? Sorry, but I do not know this language yet...

Comment: Oops, sorry. I thought this was posted under Python :(

Comment: No problem, just could you give me some usage hints...?

Comment: Can you show me some line about the usage of this code? I got some error messages when I tried to run...

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution. It converts the input into this format:

```
1|0
2|1 2
3|2
4|0 0 0 0
5|0
6|0
```

The first column is group number, in second column there are number of rooms (minus one) of all its houses, sorted. To search for group with two different houses with 2 and 3 rooms, you can just `grep '|1 2$'`, to search for groups with just one house with one room, `grep '|0$'`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#-*- cperl -*-

#use Data::Dumper;

use warnings;
use strict;

sub report {
    print join ' ', sort {$a <=> $b} @_;
    print "\n";
}

my $group = 1;
my @last = (0);
print '1|';
my @houses = ();
while (<>) {
    if (/^$/) { # group end
        report(@houses, $last[1]);
        undef @houses;
        print ++$group, '|';
        @last = (0);
    } else {
        my @tuple = split;
        if ($tuple[0] != $last[0]) { # new house
            push @houses, $last[1];
        }
        @last = @tuple;
    }
}

report(@houses, $last[1]);
```

It is based on the fact that for each house, only the last line is important.