# Pattern decoding II

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pattern decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765060/pattern-decoding)

I have some new question concerning to the previous post about pattern decoding:

I have almost the same data file, BUT there are double empty (blank) lines, which have to be taken into account in the decoding. 
So, the double empty lines mean that there was a street/grout (for definitions see the previous post: [Pattern decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765060/pattern-decoding)) in which there was zero (0) house, but we have to count these kind of patterns too. (Yes, you may think, that this is absolutely wrong statement, because there is no street without at least one house, but this is just an analogy, so please, just accept it as it is.)

Here is the ***new*** data file, with the double lines:

```
0 0    # <--- Group 1 -- 1 house (0) and 1 room (0)

0 0    # <--- Group 2 -- 2 houses (0;1) and 3,2 rooms (0,1,2;0,1)
0 1
0 2    
1 0    # <--- house 2 in Group 2, with the first room (0)
1 1    # <--- house 2 in Group 2, with the second room (1)

0 0    # <--- Group 3
0 1    # <--- house 1 in Group 3, with the second room (1)
0 2

0 0    # <--- Group 4
1 0    # <--- house 2 in Group 4, with one room only (0)
2 0
3 0    # <--- house 4 in Group 4, with one room only (0)

0 0    # <--- Group 5
       # <--- Group 6 << ---- THIS IS THE NEW GROUP

0 0    # <--- Group 7
       # <--- Group 8 << ---- THIS IS THE NEW GROUP

0 0    # <--- Group 9

0 0    # <--- Group 10
```

I need to convert this into an elegant way as it has been done before, but in this case we have to take into account these new groups too, and indicate them in this way, following ***Kent*** for example: `roupIdx houseIdx numberOfRooms`, where the `houseIdx` let equal to zero **`houseIdx = 0`** and the `numberOfRooms` let equal to zero too **`numberOfRooms = 0`**. So, I need to get this kind of **output** for example:

```
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1

6 0 0

7 0 1

8 0 0

9 0 1

10 0 1
```

Can we tune the previous code in this way?

***UPDATE: the new second empty line indicates a new group***. If there was an additional empty new line after the empty line, as in this case

```
0 0    # <--- Group 5
       # <--- Group 6 << ---- THIS IS THE NEW GROUP

0 0    # <--- Group 7
       # <--- Group 8 << ---- THIS IS THE NEW GROUP
```

we just treat the new empty line (the second one in the 2 blank lines) as a new group, and indicate them as `group_index 0 0`. See the desired output above!

Comment: Give a man a fish, and he will be back the next day for a second one? The answer to the first question gave perfectly good awk code for your problem.

Comment: Not the same problem as was before... Yeah, I know that there was a perfectly good answer in the previous post, BUT not for this present problem...

Comment: I recommend reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints , and paying particular attention to "Making a good impression".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ cat houses.awk
BEGIN{max=1;group=1}
NF==0{
   empty++
   if (empty==1) group++
   next
}
{ max = ($1 > max) ? $1 : max
   if (empty<=1){
        a[group,$1]++ 
   } else {
        a[group,$1]=-1
   }
  empty=0
}
END{for (i=1;i<=group;i++){
        for (j=0;j<=max;j++){
            if (a[i,j]>=1)
                print i , j , a[i,j]
            if (a[i,j]==-1)
                print i, j, 0
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Command:

```
awk -f houses.awk houses
```

Output:

```
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1

6 0 0

7 0 0

8 0 1
```

Comment: This is not so good, I did not get this result exactly: I got 7 0 1, 9 0 1, 10 0 1 ... somehow

Comment: We should get `6 0 0` and `7 0 0` instead of your result

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a minor remark/question: Indeed the previous code was fine in a sense that if there is double "\n\n" newline, I need to increase the group counter by one, so the `6 0 0`, `7 0 1`, `8 0 0`, `9 0 1` and `10 0 1` ***output is the correct***. Could you update the code according to this, because I erased the previous one by accident...

Comment: See the ***UPDATE*** in the post...

Comment: Please clean up the mess in your question and describe clearly what you want.

Comment: OK, I have updated the question, and the desired output. See above!

Comment: Sorry for the possible duplicate, but I need the solution... Could you give me some hints to modify your code to the new one concerning to the updated question?