# Convert column pattern

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have this kind of file:

```
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1



8 0 1


10 0 1

11 0 1
```

The RS separator is an empty line by default.

If there was a double blank line, we have to substitute on of them by a pattern `$1 0 0`, where `$1` means the increased "number" before the `$1 0 *` record.

If the separator is `empty line + 1 empty line` we have to increase the $1 by 1.
If the separator is `empty line + 2 empty line` we have to increase the $1 by 2.
...

and I need to get this output:

```
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1

6 0 0 

7 0 0

8 0 1

9 0 0

10 0 1

11 0 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? And note that this is not a "please do my work for me" site!

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have no idea how to solve this...

Comment: Take at look at this: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html. After a week of study you will know enough to advantage of the help we can offer you.

Comment: I have already looked it many times, but this is an algorithmic type of question, and simply I just do not know how to solve it...

Comment: How can I count the number of empty records? I think this is a key point, isn't it?

Comment: Is this one of your [House Room](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8841815/970195) problem? Your $3 in desired result doesn't match with Input file.

Comment: Yes it is. Ooops, that is a mistake, sorry. I have corrected, and updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this. ***The benefit of this way is that your input file need not have an empty line for the missing numbers.***

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" -v OFS="\n" '                   
BEGIN{getline; col=$1;line=$0;print line}
$1==col{print $0;next }
($1==col+1){print $0;col=$1;next}
{x=$1;y=$0; col++; while (col < x) {print col" 0 0";col++};print y;next}' file
```

### Input File:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1



8 0 1


10 0 1

11 0 1
```

#### Script Output:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" -v OFS="\n" '                   
BEGIN{getline; col=$1;line=$0;print line}
$1==col{print $0;next }
($1==col+1){print $0;col=$1;next}
{x=$1;y=$0; col++; while (col < x) {print col" 0 0";col++};print y;next}' file
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1

6 0 0

7 0 0

8 0 1

9 0 0

10 0 1

11 0 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'NF{f=0;n=$1;print;next}f{print ++n " 0 0"}{print;f=1}' ./infile
```

#### Output

```
$ awk 'NF{f=0;n=$1;print;next}f{print ++n " 0 0"}{print;f=1}' ./infile
1 0 1

2 0 3
2 1 2

3 0 3

4 0 1
4 1 1
4 2 1
4 3 1

5 0 1

6 0 0

7 0 0

8 0 1

9 0 0

10 0 1

11 0 1
```

#### Explanation

- `NF{f=0;n=$1;print;next}`: if the current line has data, unset flag `f`, save the number in the first field to `n`, print the line and skip the rest of the script
- `{print;f=1}`: We only reach this action if the current line is blank.  If so, print the line and set the flag `f`
- `f{print ++n " 0 0"}`: We only execute this action if the flag `f` is set which only happens if the previous line was blank.  If we enter this action, print the missing fields with an incremented `n`

Comment: Thats a really nice solution. Can you please explain what it does?